# How to backup iPhone over WiFi without iCloud?

Tags: iphone, backup

Whenever I connect my iPhone to my wifi, I want it to automatically create a backup to either my MacBook Pro or to a NAS, so that I can be sure my iPhone data is always backed up without having to think about it.
I do NOT want to backup to iCloud.

Is this possible in 2022?

Comment: What have you tried already to do this?

Comment: What products have you looked at? iMazing is best known.

Comment: I found this question very pertinent and the given answer useful, though it does not address all aspects of the question (which involved automating a process).  I've been a mac user for some decades and an iPhone user for much less time.  I'm baffled as to why the question was deemed to be off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Manual backup is straight out of the box functionality with macOS. Follow the Mac steps and in options select **show this iPhone when on Wi-Fi**.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203977

For speed I recommend the first backup be wired, but the incremental sync and backup work over Wi-Fi. I don't know how to harness up Shortcuts to trigger this automatically, so you may need to set a periodic alarm if you don't see sync covering backup regularly on your network.

Comment: How do you enable the backup over wifi? Are you sure it's really the backup that can be executed that way over wifi and not just the sync? I know that sync works over wifi, but I want to update the backup over wifi

Comment: Backups work over wifi for me in the past  - just not automatic

Comment: That's the crucial thing - I want a setup where I don't need to think about it anymore

Comment: iCloud is the way for set and forget - apple did all the work there for you already but I understand you may not want their vision of easy @matthias_buehlmann

Comment: But that doesn't answer my question. My question was specifically how to have automatic backups via WiFi without iCloud (there are many reasons why one wouldn't want to use iCloud). I don't understand how there can't be a simple, automatic backup to local storage whenever connected to wifi.

Comment: There’s not much to understand. It’s not programmed that way - this is the best you can do